# Move element from collection to other collection as smooth as possible

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, observablecollection

I have a GUI in WPF bound with two ItemsControls to a collection of collections: `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<T>>`.

[image: Collection of collections]

When I move an object (a gray block) within the black block (inner collection), I can use the `ObservableCollection<T>.Move()` method. This works very smooth. However, when I would like to move a gray object out of its collection to an other collection (an other black box) I need to remove it from the source collection and add it to the destination collection (the red arrow on the image). This is pretty slow because this gray box is a pretty big view element in the WPF application. Is there a way to do this smooth? Something like the `ObservableCollection.Move` but then from one collection to another?

Any hints in the right direction for smooth movement across collections are appreciated.

Comment: There's no straightforward way I can think of. Problem is: You have ItemControls that need to be informed about changes. A move from one collection to another *requires* removal in one collection, and insertion into another (and associated UI updates for both). You're best bet is probably a custom control, managing *all* items, and arrange them *as though* they were in separate collections. That way you avoid the removal and insertion of UI childs that represent the items and corresponding layout cycles (most likely the expensive part), and instead just rearrange the UI children.

Comment: I guess that's the only way to solve this. What a pity. Thanks for your time though.